How can i parse program data in program event
I used logsSubscribe to grab the events as follows

How do I parse the program data into the data structure encapsulating the events in the following code to get the values of a, b, c, d, f?


There's a proposal about event logging: Program log binary data
The program data is a base64-encoded string.
It starts with an 8-byte event discriminator followed by each field data, similar to Ethereum.
In the above example:

Discriminator: sha256("event:TokenTransaction")[:8] -> 3a239e0380c2e305
Field data:
12345 (u64) -> 0000000000003039
67890 (u64) -> 0000000000010932
23456 (u64) -> 0000000000005ba0
78901 (u64) -> 0000000000013435
1624371600 (i64) -> 0000000060d1f190



By combining all and encoding to base64, we'll get: OiOeA4DC4wUAAAAAAAAwOQAAAAAAAQkyAAAAAAAAW6AAAAAAAAE0NQAAAABg0fGQ
